# casperjs: trouble scraping an item viewed number from a page

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, timeout, casperjs

The page I want to scrape is http://v.qq.com/page/k/9/2/k0188qdxy92.html, it is hosted in China  so it takes some time to load. The data I want from this page is just the played count of the video, located southeast to the player, its selector is as shown in the picture[image].

When you open the page, you will notice that this number will display much later then other parts of the page.

```
var time1 = Date.now();
var time2;
var casper = require('casper').create();

var url = 'http://v.qq.com/page/k/9/2/k0188qdxy92.html';
casper.start(url,function(){
  time2 = Date.now();
  console.log((time2-time1)/1000);
  this.echo(this.fetchText('.played_count em'));
})
casper.run();
```

This is what I tried at first. Yesterday it worked, but today every time it just print a blank line and return to the shell. I think it is probably because the number was requested asynchronously and the network is slow. So I added a wait time into the script:

```
var time1 = Date.now();
var time2;
var casper = require('casper').create();

var url = 'http://v.qq.com/page/k/9/2/k0188qdxy92.html';
casper.start(url);
casper.wait('6000',function(){
  time2 = Date.now();
  console.log((time2-time1)/1000);
  this.echo(this.fetchText('.played_count em'));
})
casper.run();
```

Although it is slow to open the page, 60s is absolutely enough. However, this is what I get:
[image]

You can see only 1 out of 4 attempts I get the right number, which means my code is working, although something else is preventing me from always getting the right data. What is it? Could it be the network, or some script on the page?

I also tried using `waitForSelector`, and `waitFor`, but every time I get error message like  `waittimeout expired, exiting`, even though I set the `waitTimeout` option to `30000` or `60000`. I am really stuck here. Although I am new to casperjs, but I've successful scraped similar data from other video sites' pages, what is so special about this one?

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.